# Scroll map inside scrollview automatically while scrolling scrollview

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-scrollview

How to scroll map automatically which is inside scrollview like **Expedia Application**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.
First create custom scrollview.
Put mapview inside scrollview.
Then on onScrollChanged of custom scrollview, scroll the mapview like,

On CustomScrollView.java:

```
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) 
{
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    scrollMap(l,t);
}
```

On YourActivity.java:

```
public void scrollMap(int x, int y)
{
    int scrollLength = scrollView.getMeasuredHeight();
    int mapViewHeight = mapView.getMeasuredHeight();

    int mapViewCenter = (int)(mapViewHeight/2);
    int scrollMapHeight = (mapViewCenter + ((int)((mapViewHeight*y)/scrollLength)));

    scrollMapHeight = (int)((mapViewCenter - scrollMapHeight)/(1.5));

    if(scrollMapHeight<0)           
    mapView.scrollTo(x, scrollMapHeight);       
}
```